# WebDriverException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting this exception in few tests:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The process has not exited yet
>   therefore no result is available ...
>       Command duration or timeout: 39.78 seconds
>       Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09'
>       System info: host: 'WIN-08RDCDUO0CH', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.

Chrome driver capabilities:

```
chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", 
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\downloads");
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
webCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
webCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, 
chromeOptions);
```

I changed Chrome Driver and Selenium versions, but no luck. 
Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: It happen sometimes .Again load the libraries and restart your eclipse and if possible restart your machine as well. I do the same thing and it works.

Comment: Hi @SiddheshKalgaonkar, thanks for your comment. 
For me it is not an ideal solution to restart the machine after each run.
To do reboot for AWS instance it takes long time to have the instance ready and start the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using any WebDriver if you face any issue, you need to revisit 3 places:

1. Where and how are you initializing the WebDriver?
2. What options or capabilities are you defining? Are they valid?
3. How and when are you closing the WebDriver instances?

In the question you have mentioned details only about point 2. It would be nice to have an updated question mentioning details about point 1 & 3.

**Nonetheless, it is essential that instance(s) of web driver are terminated either by using `.close()` for active instance or `.quit()` for all instances.**

A sign of invalid failure termination of chrome driver can be seen in the Windows Task Manager Processes section, where you will see multiple processes of `chromedriver.exe` running even though no browser is active/open.

In such a scenario you execute a shell script to terminate all `chromedriver.exe` processes:

`TASKKILL /IM "chromedriver.exe" /F`